# Why did the data get deleted when the condition did not match in the query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have this schema in my mongo db.

```
const movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    year: Number,
    score: Number,
    rating: String
})
```

When I tried to delete collections with year greater than 1999, I have mistakenly put the condition as:

```
 Movie.deleteMany({yeaer: {$gte: 1999}}).then(res => {console.log(res)})
```

This happened
[image: This happened]

And all of my data got deleted
[image: Before and after deletion]

Comment: Safe guard your self just as @Christian said but you also misspelt the year (yeaer) in or delete query

Comment: Yeah, actually my question was why did it delete everything when i passed down a wrong query with no matching records

Comment: Wow!  Deleting everything is scary!  In `pymongo`, I tried `delete_many` on a toy collection using your same non-matching filter and fortunately it returned `deleted_count` as `0` and I verified the collection was completely intact.  Phew!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you omit the conditional property from `deleteMany()`, mongoose will delete all documents from the model. The same is true if you misspell the conditional. It's a rather dangerous default behaviour but you can guard yourself by disabling strict querying mode in mongoose:

```
mongoose.set('strictQuery', false)
```